# Switching rows of table only works for 2nd time

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here's a simple HTML `<table>` with 2 rows, each row having links to move the row up/down:

```html
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Row A</td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="up(this)">Up</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="down(this)">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row B</td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="up(this)">Up</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="down(this)">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function up(link) {
        var row = link.parentNode.parentNode;
        var prevRow = row.previousSibling;
        if (prevRow != null) {
            row.parentNode.insertBefore(row, prevRow);
        }
    }
    function down(link) {
        var row = link.parentNode.parentNode;
        var nextRow = row.nextSibling;
        if (nextRow != null) {
            row.parentNode.insertBefore(nextRow, row);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Why is it that clicking on `Down` link of the first row does nothing at first (no errors), but works for second click? Similarly clicking on the `Up` link of the 2nd row does nothing at first, but starts working afterwards?

Moreover, if I click on a link that cannot be executed (e.g. `Up` of the first row or `Down` of the last row), then the other link of the same row that should work (`Down` of the first row) doesn't work on subsequent click, but works if clicked again?

What should I do / change so that links work on first click as they should  be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because whitespace is also a node `previousSibling` / `nextSibling` returns `#text` on your first call to any of your functions, after that it fixes itself. So to get it to work the first time change to `previousElementSibling` / `nextElementSibling`

```html
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Row A</td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="up(this)">Up</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="down(this)">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row B</td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="up(this)">Up</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="down(this)">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function up(link) {
        var r = link.parentNode.parentNode;
        var rp = r.previousElementSibling;
        if (rp != null) {
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(r, rp);
        }
    }
    function down(link) {
        var r = link.parentNode.parentNode;
        var rn = r.nextElementSibling;
        if (rn != null) {
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(rn, r);
        }
    }
</script>
```